# Use 'request-promise-native' package in DialogFlow inline editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am making a POST request to a webservice. The code for POST request is kept in a separate function.The function call from my intent function to the external function is asynchronous.So i am using Promises to achieve synchronicity.The problem here is that when i am importing `request-promise-native` inside my inline editor it's throwing error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`.

But when i tried it in my local workstation which has node js version `9.11.1` it worked fine.The Node JS version in DialogFlow is `>=6.0`.Is there any other dependency has to be added to it?

Can anyone please explain why this happens?

UPDATE:
I changed the node engine to `6.14.3` and the dependency for the module'request-promise-native' in package.json as `"request-promise-native":"v1.0.5"`.But still no luck.The below is my code:

```js
var doco;
 var rp = require('request-promise-native');
 var myJSONObject = {
  "inputs" : [  {
    "name" : "<name>",
    "value" : <value>
  } ]
};
var orchName = 'TEST05';
  postData = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject);
 return networkCall(postData,orchName).then((response)=>{
   console.log('response is'+response)            
             console.log("+++++++++++++=DOCO=+++++++++ "+response);
             doco = doco1;
             //agent.add(`Order number is ${doco1}`);
             
        }).catch((response) => {
      console.log(`ERROR: `+response);
    });
 
console.log('doco'+doco); 

function networkCall(postData, orchName) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      var options = {
  method: 'post',
  uri: '<URL>',
  body: myJSONObject,
  auth: {
        'user': 'usr',
        'pass': 'pwd'
      },
  json: true
};
return rp( options )
  .then( body => {
  // var test = JSON.stringify(body)
  var doco =body.ServiceRequest1.subforms.z_DOCO_137.value;
 console.log('DOCO '+doco);
    resolve( doco );
  })
  .catch( err => {
   console.log('FAILED'+err);
    reject( err );
  });
    });
}
```

The error is thrown once i deploy the code in inline editor.The error is:

```
The deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at module.exports (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:34:47)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise-native/lib/rp.js:15:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:17:23)
```

Comment: The node version used by the Dialogflow editor is 6.14.3. Try testing with that version and see if you can reproduce the error. If so, please update your question with the version of request-promise-native you're using, a minimal example of the code, and the full error message you're getting.

Comment: I have updated my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request-promise-native` package requires the `request` package as a co-dependency. So you need to explicitly add this to the `package.json` tab in the Dialogflow editor.

[image]

Here is the `package.json` that works for me:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.3",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0",
    "request": "^2.87"
  }
}
```

Don't forget that, in addition to having the correct package, you will need to upgrade the project to a paid account. The free Firebase "Spark" plan does not allow network access outside of Google's network. You can upgrade to the "Blaze" plan which is pay-as-you-go, but does have a free tier which is sufficient for most development and testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the `Package.json` file.Now i am able to use the `request-promise-native` module.But the problem now is,Google assistant is not waiting for the promise to be returned from the called function.The response from called function takes about 7 seconds to complete.is there a way to make the intent handler to wait for the response?

Comment: There are a number of answers to that, depending on some details that are best addressed as an additional question. I'd suggest you ask a new StackOverflow question providing the code you're using, including the intent handler function setup, which you don't include here. If this answer works, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: I figured it out.I optimized my code so that my external function doesnt run more than 5 seconds.The returned value from the function to intent handler is now sent to user by text and also as speech.Thank you very much.It would not be possible without your `package.json` file.

Comment: Glad you got it working! If the answer helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.